# PCRE: Return offset number of matching subpattern

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm looking to group large numbers of patterns that are to matched against various HTML elements, attributes and text in web documents.

For example, I may be interested in the contents of the `<title>` element and have a regex like this:

```
pcre *test_filter = pcre_compile("(google|stackoverflow|expertsexchange)",0,&error,&erroffset,NULL);
```

If I were to test against the input string of "stackoverflow", I'm wondering if it's somehow possible to reference the offset within that group, i.e. 1 in this case, 0 for google and 2 for experstexchange.

Ideally I'm going to concatenate a bunch of text strings, and it seems like that would be the most obvious way to understand which member of the group matched, rather than performing further regexes.

Does such functionality exist with `pcre`?

Comment: expert sex change?

Comment: i was going to go for penisland, but expertsexchange seemed more relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RE pattern you give is good for finding the *value* of the string that matched, but you'd then have to (at least) look up the matched value in order to get an index into the group.  If you change the pattern to have each word in its own capturing group, then you can use the return value from `pcre_exec()` to get the index (plus 1) of the last capturing group.

If the pattern is `"(google)|(stackoverflow)|(expertsexchange)"`, then if `google` was matched, `pcre_exec()` would return `1` (or `2` for `stackoverflow` &c).

When preparing your regular expression, I'd advise building it from a list of strings in reverse-sorted order; this puts longer matches before shorter (contained) matches, and even if you use something more complex, it's usually a good place to start.

Comment: This answers the question but I'd advise you to skip using regexes for such a thing and just use plain old string functions - there's no advantage to regexes there. If you *do* need a more complex pattern though, use the `ovector` parameter to inspect which group matched.

Comment: I agree that when plain old string functions can do the job, they're the best way to go, but I've used this pattern (mostly in Python) to build some very complex lexers with very good performance.  The question asked specifically if there was a simple way to get an integer telling what string was matched, and the return from `pcre_exec()` is exactly that, without the work of scanning the `ovector`.  If the return value wasn't what it is, I would have suggested scanning the `ovector`, but checking the man page told me there is a better way.

Comment: Yes, I agree you can use the return value when the pattern is *exactly* like in your answer, I was just saying you can't rely solely on it if the pattern gets more complex than that.

Comment: We are in violent agreement :-)  I am the last person that would say it's trivial to get the regex correctly defined, but at the same time, I can say that non-capturing groups ( `(?: )` ) make using the returned index a very usable strategy.

Comment: I find this as a workaround but not an answer to original question: *to reference the offset within that group*

Comment: It's not exactly the same RE as given, but the question was phrased using "Somehow possible" and "ideally", and I thought that "No." wasn't a very helpful answer, no matter how technically correct it would be.

Comment: Thanks kindly for comments. The 2nd paragraph seems like a genius way to do it, I hadn't thought of that and it would achieve what I had in mind. My original example was simplified as there will be some subpatterns e.g. matching script src tags and seeing what version of jquery is used `[^/+]?jquery(-\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?(\.min)?\.js` ... I was mainly aiming to avoid doing further regex after knowing that at least one pattern matched, and then using some external data structures to know which.